# Shrink Wrap Facility at Newark airport?

Tags: luggage, ewr

Is the shrink wrap (plastic wrapping luggage) facility available at Newark Liberty International Airport?

I have to catch flight from Terminal B and want to shrink wrap my luggage before check-in.

Answer (score 2):

A 2013 directory of luggage wrap services is available [here](http://www.protectabag.com.au/uploads/7/6/1/4/76149701/global_wrapping_directory.pdf).

The main luggage wrap services appear to be:

- [Seal & Go](http://www.sealandgo.com/locations/)
- [TruStar](http://www.truestargroup.com/where-we-operate.php)
- [Secure Wrap](http://www.securewrap.com/whereweoperate.php?languageid=1)

From the directory and the above sites, there appears to be no published baggage wrap presence at Newark. There are indications on Flyertalk that EWR might have had this service at some point. The [airport website](http://www.panynj.gov/airports/newark-liberty.html) gives no listing for this service either.

Update: I checked with the airport and was confirmed that none of the terminals have a luggage wrap service.

Comment: How does the luggage wrapping work with the TSA opening the bags for checking?  Lately, every time I flew out of USA, I would find a piece of paper inside my suitcase indicating that the bag was opened and checked.  I believe some airports now operate "100% of bags checked" policy.

Comment: They would just cut it off

Comment: @AleksG that perhaps explains why such services are no longer offered.

Comment: They seem to be pretty rare in the US compared to Europe. I can't believe they have 100% checking though

Comment: @Berwyn not in all airports